# How to set a custom user agent using iOS Google Analytics API?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have implemented Google Analytics tracking in my iOS app and it is working, however when viewing the stats for "Browser" the value seems to be hardcoded to "GoogleAnalytics".

Is there a way I can override the user-agent string when using GANTracker so I can set custom values to include my app version and device version?

I'm using custom variables for this at the moment but doing it that way feels clunky.

Comment: Have you tried signing up for Google Mobile App Analytics? I haven't tried it yet so I don't know if your issue would be present there as well. The sign-up page is here: https://services.google.com/fb/forms/mobileappanalyticsbeta/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking through the SDK. In the public interface of the **GANTracker** there are no methods or properties that would allow you to override the name of the agent.

Then, overriding that value would require probably to reverse-engineer the static library (.a) to see if it's possible to override or call a private method or variable to manually set the agent, but this would not be allowed by the [ToS of the SDK](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html).

So, to cut a long story short, I believe you can't.